# How do I update/install new tools for installed visual studio IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I already have visual studio 2015 installed on my computer and when I first installed it I only selected visual C++ option (no tools) to install since I was only worried about coding on windows desktop. Now, I want to download and install the C++ Cross-Platform Mobile Development tools for my visual studio version. Everywhere I looked talks about doing this when downloading visual studio for the first time. My question is is there a way to add on the tools to my current visual studio 2015 installation? Or do I really have to re-download visual studio again and select the mobile tools option on the install page?

Comment: The online installer is small enough to download, and using that you would be able to download and install components on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-open the Visual Studio installer program via the Programs and Features control panel:

[image]